# Unicorn restarts with same PID on USR2

Tags: ubuntu, ruby-on-rails, unicorn

Having recently migrated our Rails app to MRI 2.2.0 (which may or may not be related), we’re experiencing problems with our Unicorn zero-downtime restarts.

When I send the USR2 signal to the master process (PID 19216 in this example), I get the following in the Unicorn log:

```
I, [2015-03-11T23:47:33.992274 #6848]  INFO -- : executing ["/srv/ourapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/unicorn", "/srv/ourapp/current/config.ru", "-Dc", "/srv/ourapp/shared/config/unicorn.rb", {10=>#<Kgio::UNIXServer:/srv/ourapp/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock>}] (in /srv/ourapp/releases/a0e8b5df474ad5129200654f92a76af00a750f47)
I, [2015-03-11T23:47:36.504235 #6848]  INFO -- : inherited addr=/srv/ourapp/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock fd=10
/srv/ourapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:206:in `pid=': Already running on PID:19216 (or pid=/srv/ourapp/shared/pids/unicorn.pid is stale) (ArgumentError)
 from /srv/ourapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:134:in `start'
 from /srv/ourapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.1/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
 from /srv/ourapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
 from /srv/ourapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
E, [2015-03-11T23:47:36.519549 #19216] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 6848 exit 1> exec()-ed
E, [2015-03-11T23:47:36.520296 #19216] ERROR -- : master loop error: Already running on PID:19216 (or pid=/srv/ourapp/shared/pids/unicorn.pid is stale) (ArgumentError)
E, [2015-03-11T23:47:36.520496 #19216] ERROR -- : /srv/ourapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:206:in `pid='
E, [2015-03-11T23:47:36.520650 #19216] ERROR -- : /srv/ourapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:404:in `reap_all_workers'
E, [2015-03-11T23:47:36.520790 #19216] ERROR -- : /srv/ourapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:279:in `join'
E, [2015-03-11T23:47:36.520928 #19216] ERROR -- : /srv/ourapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.1/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
E, [2015-03-11T23:47:36.521115 #19216] ERROR -- : /srv/ourapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
E, [2015-03-11T23:47:36.521254 #19216] ERROR -- : /srv/ourapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>’
```

And when I check, indeed, there is now unicorn.pid and unicorn.pid.oldbin, both containing 19216.

What could cause this situation to arise?

Here’s our unicorn.rb FWIW:

```
# Set your full path to application.
app_path = "/srv/ourapp/current"

# Set unicorn options
worker_processes 3
preload_app true
timeout 30
listen "/srv/ourapp/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock", :backlog => 64

# Spawn unicorn master worker for user deploy (group: deploy)
user 'deploy', 'deploy'

# Fill path to your app
working_directory app_path

# Should be 'production' by default, otherwise use other env
rails_env = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'production'

# Log everything to one file
stderr_path "/srv/ourapp/shared/log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "/srv/ourapp/shared/log/unicorn.log"

# Set master PID location
pid "/srv/ourapp/shared/pids/unicorn.pid"

before_exec do |server|
 ENV["BUNDLE_GEMFILE"] = "#{app_path}/Gemfile"
end

before_fork do |server, worker|
 ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!

 sleep 10

 old_pid = "#{server.config[:pid]}.oldbin"
 if File.exists?(old_pid) && server.pid != old_pid
   begin
     Process.kill("QUIT", File.read(old_pid).to_i)
   rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
     # someone else did our job for us
   end
 end
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
 ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection

 Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
   config.redis = { namespace: 'sidekiq' }
 end
end
```

Comment: Erik Wong responded to this in a public forum at https://bogomips.org/unicorn-public/20150320020836.GA32651@dcvr.yhbt.net/T/